# How to obtain $\operatorname{Gal}(f\mid \mathbb{Q}_3)=A_3$ or $S_3$?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, p-adic-number-theory, splitting-field

I'm doing a lot of Galois Theory lately. Now I'm more and more into $p$-adic fields. My goal is to choose an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ and $\mathbb{Q}_3$ such that you obtain $A_3$ or $S_3$ as its Galois group. Is there an easy way to find such a polynomial? Could you shortly explain by an example?

Comment: Show that a monic irreducible cubic has Galois group $A_3$ if its discriminant $\Delta$ is a square and $S_3$ if it isn't.

Comment: You might find the [database of $p$-adic fields](https://www.lmfdb.org/padicField/) in the LMFDB to be a useful reference; it includes all degree $n$ extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all $n \leq 15$ and $p < 200$.

Answer (score 1):

- What is the Galois group of (the splitting field of) $x^3-p \in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ for $p=2,3$ and for arbitrary $p$ ?
- What is the Galois group of $\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^3-1})/\Bbb{Q}_p$ ?

Comment: Your first question : Ive found via google both times its $S_3$ but I dont know why it is that way

Comment: In case of p=2: As far as I know the 7-th primitive root would generate a field extension of degree 6.

Comment: If $x^3-p$ doesn't split completely in $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/3})$ then its splitting field $L$ has degree $6$ and $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ is the whole of $S_3$. No $[\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_7):\Bbb{Q}]=6$ doesn't mean that $[\Bbb{Q}_2(\zeta_7):\Bbb{Q}_2]=6$.

Comment: So I'm showing via Hensels Lemma that polynomial has no root in a p-adic field thus its irreducible there. But how do I easily show then it doesnt split in that splitting field completely?